# Sandboxie vs VMs

Tags: virtual-machine, sandboxie

For basic browsing, and simple application installing, is Sandboxie enough?
Are there times where a VM would offer better security?

Answer (score 1):

It is just guessing but I would say it depends on the balance of whichever of the applications is more popular and more stable(fewer vulnerabilities).

Afaik malware writers generally write exploits for software that is:

- popular
- has vulnerability

So if you pick a not so well known virtualization software that is very stable, you have less chances of catching malware.

Comment: nice answer.  you brought up a point i hadn't considered.

Comment: actually for even better security one could run sandboxie inside the vm, but this is for true fans of bdsm :)